# Questions about the split of feature in the buidling of decition tree

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

i am studying the Decision tree algorithm and i read the sklearn source code. When i read the part of the spliting of a feature in the buliding of decision tree, i meet a question in the _splitter.pyx file which is located in the floder sklearn/tree. I have two questions, the first is , everytime doing the split, the algorithm choose a feature randomly? Because the randomness, does one feature can be choose for more than one times? I am so confused about this question and i will appreciate it if you guys can give me this help. the sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx is in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, the algo does selects features randomly to avoid overfitting. You can use `max_features` parameter to control the number of randomly selected features which can be considered for a split.